# How to update existing entity type values in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, eav-attributes

I created custom entity type which existing in **eav_entity_type** table.

But, I want to update value of **entity_model, attribute_model & etc.**

How to update it?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create **UpgradeData.php** script and update value using below code :

```
<?php
namespace VendorName\ModuleName\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use VendorName\ModuleName\Setup\ModuleNameSetup;

class UpgradeData implements UpgradeDataInterface
{
    /**
     * @var EavSetupFactory
     */
    protected $eavSetupFactory;

    /**
     * [__construct description]
     * @param EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory [description]
     */
    public function __construct(
        EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
    )
    {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }

    public function upgrade(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context) {

        $setup->startSetup();

        /** @var EavSetup $eavSetup */
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.0.1', '<')) {
            $entityType = $eavSetup->getEntityTypeId(ModuleNameSetup::ENTITY_TYPE_CODE);

            $data = [
                'entity_type_code' => ModuleNameSetup::ENTITY_TYPE_CODE, //your entity_type_code
                'entity_model' => \VendorName\ModuleName\Model\ResourceModel\ModuleName::class,
                'attribute_model' => \VendorName\ModuleName\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute::class,
                'entity_table' => ModuleNameSetup::ENTITY_TYPE_CODE, //your entity_table name
                'entity_attribute_collection' => \VendorName\ModuleName\Model\ResourceModel\Attribute\Collection::class
                // add fields which you want to update value
            ];
            $eavSetup->updateEntityType(ModuleNameSetup::ENTITY_TYPE_CODE, $data);
        }
        $setup->endSetup();
    }
}
```

> Note : Make sure before upgrade, your module's `setup_version` is 1.0.1

Hope, It will helpful for you.